What's keeping me from running/deleting projects in Visual Studio and Unity?
With Visual Studio, VS Code, and Unity, I keep running into the same two problems (if it matters, I'm coding in C# in all of these). When I'm trying to run (or sometimes even just open) a project, I get an error along the lines of "Cannot [Read / Write ] data with a User-Mapped Section Open". Usually I'm able to open the project (sometimes this has to be in Safe Mode), but I can't actually run my projects at all.
So I think, fine, I'll just delete it and start another project, maybe something went wrong creating the project. But when I go to delete the given project folder, I get something along the lines of "File is Open in Another Program". And again, this happens whether it's a project I'm making in one of the VS's, or in Unity. Same problem.
So given this, one would think that something else has a handle on my projects folders (or a file within them), for some reason. I've tried using Process Explorer and Resource Manager, but I can't figure out what's locking up my project folders. The only thing I could find that looks like it could potentially be the problem is my anti-virus (specifically, WebRoot's WRSkyClient) holding onto/scanning these folders. Would that make any sense, having my anti-virus prevent me from running/deleting projects? Granted, I'm not an expert or especially experienced with either of these tools, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.
This seems to ONLY be a problem for programming-related projects. I make digital art, play games, etc on the same computer and don't run into the same issue with literally anything else. Yes, I've also tried resetting my computer and turning it off and on. I also tried clearing temp folders, didn't help either.
I've been losing my mind over this for over a month, I need to be able able to work on projects so I can build up my portfolio and further develop my programming skills, and this is literally making it impossible.
Any and all help on this would be very greatly appreciated.

webroot has had major issues with programming compilers.. especially because it has the daft idea that you should never exclude anything under any circumstances.

@BugFinder That seems to be what the problem was. I paused Webroot, and suddenly I can delete the folders I want to delete and it'll let me compile new projects without the console throwing up a bunch of weird errors. Huh...

Id never use it for that reason. Anything arrogant enough to believe it cant ever cause an issue. Inevitably does.   Uninstall. Find something else.
